# how to set core data relationship to NSNull()?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I have a simple NSMO that has a relationship field. Sometimes I need to delete the relationship but preserve the object. Here is the object, it has a to-one relationship to Person (person has to-many back to LineUp):

```
@objc (LineUp)
class LineUp: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var roleType: String
    @NSManaged var roleName: String
    @NSManaged var person: Person
}
```

Then when I try to do this:

```
for role in arrayOfRoles as [LineUp] {
    if someCondition == true {
        role.person = NSNull()
        moc.save(&error)
    }
}
```

I just get 'NSNull is not convertible to Person'. My workaround is obvious and expensive: I am deleting and recreating the object. Any tips?

Update post answer: I was trying to set my relationship to nil from the wrong side. IE 
    for person in personArray {
        for role in person.roles {
            if someCondition == true {
                role.person = nil
    }
    }
    }

If I just get the object ID of the role, then go from there it works. But not when I'm on the 'many' side of the relationship. No big deal, sorry for such a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it to `nil` is how you indicate there's nothing on the other end of the relationship. `NSNull` is used when you want to represent nil in an Objective-C collection, and is more or less made obsolete by optionals.

Comment: I swear I tried that already.. you have no idea how hard Im kicking myself right now... thanks :)